# ESLint no-return-assign and no-param-reassign error in React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, eslint

I have this code in React App to load my chat messages:

```
  const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i = 0) => {
    <div className={`${classes.bubbleContainer} ${obj.direction}`} key={i}>
      <div key={(i += 1)} className={classes.bubble}>
        <div className={classes.button}>{obj.message}</div>
      </div>
    </div>;
  });
  return <div className={classes.container}>{chatBubbles}</div>;
```

This is working, but I'm getting two errors in ESLint and I don't know how to fix it

```
  error  Expected to return a value in arrow function                           array-callback-return
  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  error  Assignment to function parameter 'i'                                   no-param-reassign
```

How can I rewrite this code snippet so that my Eslint will accept?

Comment: Did you read the relevant rules' pages in the docs? They all have examples of valid and invalid code according to the rule.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I read it, but I didn't understand what to do in this case

Comment: Map does not return anything....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to make it like this:

```
    const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${classes.bubbleContainer} ${obj.direction}`} key={i}>
            <div key={(i + 1)} className={classes.bubble}>
                <div className={classes.button}>{obj.message}</div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    )
});
return <div className={classes.container}>{chatBubbles}</div>;
```

`error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` and `error  Expected to return a value in arrow function` - you need to return something from map callback

`error  Assignment to function parameter 'i'` - you should not reassign `i`
(`i += 1` change to `i + 1`)

Answer (score 2):

First issue: No reason to set a default value!

```
const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i = 0) => { <-- there should not be a `= 0`
```

Second issue: No return inside the block

```
const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i = 0) => { <-- there { should be a ( <div/> ) or { return (<div/>) }
```

Third issue: Incrementing index which is set by map

```
(i += 1) <-- Why are you increasing the variable i?
```

---

```
const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i) => (
  <div className={`${classes.bubbleContainer} ${obj.direction}`} key={i}>
    <div key={(i + 1)} className={classes.bubble}>
      <div className={classes.button}>{obj.message}</div>
    </div>
  </div>;
));
return <div className={classes.container}>{chatBubbles}</div>;
```

I am not sure why you are adding one to the second key...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pre-assign `i` when using the `map()` function on arrays. Replace the first line with this:

```js
  const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i) => {
```